# Code not working is js seprate file but it works when i put it in a <script>

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

So as the title says, i want to create a loader but the script works when i put it in the html file but i doesn't when i put it in my sperate js file.

Here's the script:

```js
var loader = document.getElementById("ld");
    window.addEventListener("load", function()
    {
      loader.style.display = "none";
    })
```

and here's the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="author" content="Bilal el Badaoui">
<meta name="description" content="The best clothes for the best price">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>S&B Clothes</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="logo/icons8-needle-96.png">
</head>

<body id="body">

<div class="loader" id="ld"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: `Not working` is a poor description. What does the Dev tool console say? `Type reference Error: Element is null`? Add a `defer` Attribute to the script ag and see if it fix it. PS: You proberly also want `DOMContentLoaded` not `load` as event.

Comment: Reference: [Window: DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: i get "Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')"

Comment: you can try including your script at the end of body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block is the problem. Change this block:

```js
var loader = document.getElementById("ld");
    window.addEventListener("load", function()
    {
      loader.style.display = "none";
    })
```

to:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
  var loader = document.getElementById("ld");
  loader.style.display = "none";
})
```

**Why?**
You include your js script in the head of your dom. Then you have to wait if the entire dom is loaded. Because your script will start to select a element which is not loaded. For this reason you have to put your code inside the load event.

Comment: Hello @Quentin! Can you explain why, please? Thank you :-)

Comment: you should use `DOMContentLoaded` not load as an event. Also, style changes in 2023 should be made at the CSS level.

Answer (score 0):

The code is read from top to bottom, so at first it reads the script and don't see the id "ld", after script he reads body and now see the id. So you must put script after div to read it first, and then the script can see items of body. So put script at the end of body.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="author" content="Bilal el Badaoui">
<meta name="description" content="The best clothes for the best price">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>S&B Clothes</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="logo/icons8-needle-96.png">
</head>

<body id="body">

<div class="loader" id="ld"></div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

P.S. sorry for my English)

Comment: It can solve the issue but it is the most inefficient method (no asynchronous loading)

Answer (score -1):

If you are having issues linking to your external js file, can you just try adding the line below to test that?
And can you also share if the js file is in the same directory as your html file or in a different directory?
If both files are in the same directory then you should get a "hello world" Message.

```
alert('hello world')
var loader = document.getElementById("ld");
    window.addEventListener("load", function()
    {
      loader.style.display = "none";
    })
```